# How to create nice user-interactive scripts in the terminal?

Tags: shell

I recently installed [bower](http://bower.io) and typing

```
$ bower init
```

in a empty directory start this really nice prompt. Not only the traditional `(Y/n)` questionary but even I was given a list of options like in the picture. I wonder what tool or program is being used to create this kind of forms?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library? Will give you this functionality

Comment: Thanks! Now I know I should have googled for "Text user interfaces" :)